# Threejs vector.unproject( this.camera ) is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

Why do I get an function is undefined error for vector.unproject while it's stated in the documentation? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3 (one of the last items)

If I console log it, it also comes back as undefined while the rest of Threejs is working A-Okey. Is it depricated? What is the replacement? I want to Raycast and click detect on a loaded .obj file and this is stated as a way of doing this.

My code [I use RequireJS and Backbone hence the way the function is structured]:

```
click: function(event){
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

        vector.set(
            ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
            - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
            0.5 );

        console.log(vector.unproject); //returns undefined
        vector.unproject( this.camera ); //stops here and returns function is undefined

        var dir = vector.sub( this.camera.position ).normalize();

        var distance = - this.camera.position.z / dir.z;

        var pos = this.camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

    },
```

Comment: Have you checked the source of the Three.js file you're using? Does it exist there? If it does exist, is the function present *just after* you create the vector? If so, *step through the code* until you see where it's being removed.

Comment: I found what was wrong. I used build .68 and for some reason it wasn't in that version. I downloaded the .69 version and there it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the projector.js, It isn't longer part of the three.js, but you found in examples/js/renderer/projector.js